# Enhanced Ecommerce for Android - events from the doc and not populating the reports

Tags: javascript, android, google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce, google-analytics-firebase

So I've been trying to implement Enhanced Ecom on an Android app with GTM. It's not working well, because add to cart and purchase events are not working.

I tried copy-pasting the recommended calls in the doc to see if it would work. Data is still not coming in the right way. Do you have an idea what can be the problem?

Here's the code:

```
TagManager tagManager = TagManager.getInstance(this);
DataLayer dataLayer = tagManager.getDataLayer();
```

Impressions (fired on pageview tag, working)

```
dataLayer.push("ecommerce",
 DataLayer.mapOf(
 "currencyCode", "EUR", // Local currency is optional.
 "impressions", DataLayer.listOf(
 DataLayer.mapOf(
 "name", "Triblend Android T-Shirt", // Name or ID is required.
 "id", "12345",
 "price", "15.25",
 "brand", "Google",
 "category", "Apparel",
 "variant", "Gray",
 "list", "Search Results",
 "position", 1),
 DataLayer.mapOf(
 "name", "Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt",
 "id", "67890",
 "price", "33.75",
 "brand", "Google",
 "category", "Apparel",
 "variant", "Black",
 "list", "Search Results",
 "position", 2))));
```

Clicks (fired with event, working)

```
dataLayer.pushEvent("productClick",
 DataLayer.mapOf(
 "ecommerce", DataLayer.mapOf(
 "click", DataLayer.mapOf(
 "actionField", DataLayer.mapOf(
 "list", "Search Results"), // Optional list property.
 "products", DataLayer.listOf(
 DataLayer.mapOf(
 "name", "Triblend Android T-Shirt", // Name or ID is required.
 "id", "12345",
 "price", "15.25",
 "brand", "Google",
 "category", "Apparel",
 "variant", "Gray"))))));
```

Detail (fired on pageview tag, working)

```
dataLayer.push("ecommerce",
 DataLayer.mapOf(
 "detail", DataLayer.mapOf(
 "actionField", DataLayer.mapOf(
 "list", "Apparel Gallery"), // detail actions have an optional list property.
 "products", DataLayer.listOf(
 DataLayer.mapOf(
 "name", "Triblend Android T-Shirt", // Name or ID is required.
 "id", "12345",
 "price", "15.25",
 "brand", "Google",
 "category", "Apparel",
 "variant", "Gray")))));
```

Add to cart (fired with custom event, the event fires in GA but no data is coming in. even though the data layer is activated on the tag)

```
dataLayer.pushEvent("addToCart",
 DataLayer.mapOf(
 "ecommerce", DataLayer.mapOf(
 "currencyCode", "EUR",
 "add", DataLayer.mapOf( // 'add' actionFieldObject measures.
 "products", DataLayer.listOf(
 DataLayer.mapOf(
 "name", "Triblend Android T-Shirt",
 "id", "12345",
 "price", "15.25",
 "brand", "Google",
 "category", "Apparel",
 "variant", "Gray",
 "quantity", 1))))));
```

Checkout (fired with event, working)

```
dataLayer.pushEvent("checkout",
 DataLayer.mapOf(
 "ecommerce", DataLayer.mapOf(
 "checkout", DataLayer.mapOf(
 "actionField", DataLayer.mapOf(
 "step", 1,
 "option", "Visa"),
 "products", DataLayer.listOf(
 DataLayer.mapOf(
 "name", "Triblend Android T-Shirt",
 "id", "12345",
 "price", "15.25",
 "brand", "Google",
 "category", "Apparel",
 "variant", "Gray",
 "quantity", 1))))));
```

To get purchase to work, we're sending a pageview right after the code, just to make sure we send a hit after to ensure data can reach GA.

```
dataLayer.push("ecommerce",
 DataLayer.mapOf(
 "purchase", DataLayer.mapOf(
 "actionField", DataLayer.mapOf(
 "id", "T12345", // Transaction ID. Required for purchases and refunds.
 "affiliation", "Online Store",
 "revenue", "35.43", // Total transaction value (incl. tax and shipping)
 "tax", "4.90",
 "shipping", "5.99",
 "coupon", "SUMMER_SALE"),
 "products", DataLayer.listOf( // List of productFieldObjects.
 DataLayer.mapOf(
 "name", "Triblend Android T-Shirt", // Name or ID is required.
 "id", "12345",
 "price", "15.25",
 "brand", "Google",
 "category", "Apparel",
 "variant", "Gray",
 "quantity", 1,
 "coupon", ""), // Optional fields may be omitted or set to empty string.
 DataLayer.mapOf(
 "name", "Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt",
 "id", "67890",
 "price", "33.75",
 "brand", "Google",
 "category", "Apparel",
 "variant", "Black",
 "quantity", 1))))); 

dataLayer.push(DataLayer.mapOf("event", "openScreen", "screenName", "TEST_SCREEN"));
  }
```

Any idea why Add To Cart and Purchase won't work with this, even though checkout info (which is sent after) is?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was going on with this?  I am running into the exact same problem